# problem typescript execution order failed

Tags: angular, typescript

I am calling a function to save some data in a first time from an object and apply my changes in the second time ( make this object empty ), the problem is I cant get the object's content

calling the function from template:

```html
<button class="btn btn-default myButton" (click)="onChangePartenaire()"
        [ngStyle]="!partenaireDisabled && {'background'  : 'gray'}">
        Creation
</button>
```

```js
ngOnInit() {

 ............
 
this.apporteur = this.simulation.apporteur;

.............

}
```

```
onChangePartenaire() { console.log('this.apporteur',this.apporteur);
        this.partInitial = this.apporteur;
        this.partenaireDisabled = !this.partenaireDisabled;

        if(!this.partenaireDisabled) { //set this.apporteur to this.partInitial before and continue
            this.apporteur.simulation_info_apporteur_nom = '';
            this.apporteur.simulation_info_vendeur.simulation_info_vendeur_nom = '';
            this.apporteur.simulation_info_vendeur.simulation_info_vendeur_prenom = '';
            this.apporteur.simulation_info_vendeur.simulation_info_vendeur_email = '';
            this.apporteur.simulation_info_vendeur.simulation_info_vendeur_tel = '';
        } else {
            this.apporteur = this.partInitial;
        }

    }
```

I try this but no result :

```
onChangePartenaire() { console.log('this.apporteur',this.apporteur);
        this.partInitial = this.apporteur;
        this.partenaireDisabled = !this.partenaireDisabled;

        let _this = this;
        setTimeout( function () {
            if(!_this.partenaireDisabled) {
                _this.apporteur.simulation_info_apporteur_nom = '';
                _this.apporteur.simulation_info_vendeur.simulation_info_vendeur_nom = '';
                _this.apporteur.simulation_info_vendeur.simulation_info_vendeur_prenom = '';
                _this.apporteur.simulation_info_vendeur.simulation_info_vendeur_email = '';
                _this.apporteur.simulation_info_vendeur.simulation_info_vendeur_tel = '';
            } else {
                _this.apporteur = _this.partInitial;
            }
        }, 100);


    }
```

thanks for helping me.

Comment: does the console.log print the actual object?

Comment: @Karim No it's empty, but will print the actuel object  without my changes ..

Comment: please try to explain again the problem cause it's not clear. and post the whole code, especially when you create this.apporteur

Comment: Plus, add the code that call the function and attach the error you are getting

Comment: I updated the code . Note : I am using angular 5

Comment: What is this: `this.simulation.apporteur`? Is it calling an async operation?

Comment: @DeborahK `this.simulation.apporteur` it's not empty, I think teh probleme is about execution order !

Comment: Yes, which is often caused by async operations. Do you have more code in ngOnInit that is doing some async processing?

Comment: Yes, I have some async operations but after loading all data ( I mean `console.log(this.apporteur)` in ngOnInit works fine ) and by clicking on btn to trigger the function `onChangePartenaire`, `console.log(this.apporteur)` will be empty !